# Why does PowerShell convert an ArrayList to a PSCustomObject when adding only one PSCustomObject?

Tags: powershell, arraylist

I am writing a code where it gets all files matching a criteria. For each file found, I create a custom object with only few of the file's ($Obj) values and then add this to an `ArrayList ($Files)`. This `ArrayList` is then returned to the invoking function and stored in the variable of it `($OldFiles)`.

This works fine when no files or more than one are found. However, if only one file is found, the `ArrayList` converts itself to an `PSCustomObject` and then it throws an exception as the return cannot convert `PSCustomObject` to `ArrayList`.

The curious part is, if I add the simple line `"$Files.getType()"` before the return statement, there is no error and the `ArrayList` remains as an `ArrayList`.

Basically, this will not work:
Simplified in the first function:

```
$Files = [System.Collections.ArrayList]@()
$Files.Add($Obj) > $null
return $Files
```

And this is how it looks in the top function:

```
$OldFiles = [System.Collections.ArrayList](Check-OldFiles -Path $Directory -Age $Age -FilesOnly:$FilesOnly -Recurse:$Recurse -UserCreationTime:$UserCreationTime)
```

But this works fine:
Simplified in the first function:

```
$Files = [System.Collections.ArrayList]@()
$Files.Add($Obj) > $null
$Files.getType()
return $Files
```

And this is how it looks in the top function:

```
$OldFiles = [System.Collections.ArrayList](Check-OldFiles -Path $Directory -Age $Age -FilesOnly:$FilesOnly -Recurse:$Recurse -UserCreationTime:$UserCreationTime)
```

Why could this possibly be happening?

`PowerShell` version is 5.0

Comment: powershell _unrolls_ a collection when sending it across the pipeline OR when returning it from a function. that means it sends it out one-at-a-time ... that also means a one-item collection will be _just one item_ when it arrives at the other end of the call. you can use a leading comma `,$Collection` to wrap the collection in an array before you send it out ... that will unwrap as a collection.

Comment: @Lee_Dailey I was aware of the unpacking when using the pipeline but I wasn't aware that it did the same when returning from a Function.
Your hint of using the comma before the Collection worked like a charm, thanks a lot!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Clarification, caution (both @Bender the Greatest) and explanation (@Phragos):

1. @() does not "wrap" its content. It converts its content to an `Array`. If its content is already an `Array` then it returns it as is. If it is a value or a single object then it copies it into a one element `Object[]`. If it is some other form of collection (e.g. `ArrayList`) then it copies each element into an `Object[]`. (Note: "@()" is an empty `Object[]`.)
2. Don't use `,(...)` to force ... to be an `Array`. The automatic unwrapping behaviour when outputting objects (display, file, printer, etc...) can be misleading.

   ```
   $myCollection = ,(get-process)
   ```

   does not leave `$myCollection` with an `Array` of processes unless there is only one process (such as from `get-process -name`). Instead, `$myCollection` will be an `Array` of a single element containing the whole output (either a single object or an `Array` of the output objects). This fact is obscured by the format output cmdlets (`Format-Table`, `Format-List` and `Format-Wide`) which examine the objects received and, if any are `Arrays`, unwrap them. (More detail [How PowerShell Formatting and Outputting REALLY works](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/powershell/how-powershell-formatting-and-outputting-really-works/)).

   You say "But if I do this it works fine":

   ```
   $myCollection | foreach { $_.starttime }
   ```

   and I say, yes, you get a list of starttimes **BUT** not the way you think. In the above, `$myCollection` is unwrapped and each element is sent into the pipeline to `foreach`. There is only one element which is an `Array` so the `foreach` loops once with `$_` set to an `Array` of processes. Since `Array` is a collection but has no starttime member, PowerShell (V3+) performs a *member enumeration* creating an `Array` consisting of the values of the starttime members of each element of `$_`. This `Array` is then unwrapped and sent into the pipeline.

   You say "So what, the effect is the same" and I reply, yes until you try something more complicated:

   ```
   $myFiles = ,(gci -file *)
   $myFiles | foreach { $_.name+' '+$_.length }
   ```

   Expected output is a list of file names and lengths. Actual output is a list of names, a blank line and the number of files. Why? `$myFiles` is an `Array` of one element containing the list of files so `foreach` loops once with `$_` being this list. An `Array` has no *name* member so PowerShell performs a *member enumeration* producing an `Array` of names. Next, a `String` of one space is added (concatenated) to this `Array`. Finally, `$_.length` is added. Since an `Array` does have a length member, this value (an `Int32`) is added to the `Array` of names and `' '`. This `Array` is then unwrapped and sent out.

   Summary, if you want something that might or might not be an `Array` to definitely be an `Array`, don't use ,(...). Always use @(...), that's what it's for.

   However, in other situations, the use of ,(...) is appropriate but can still create confusion.

   When parsing the command line, spaces separate *tokens* not arguments. Therefore, the following are equivalent:

   ```
   1,2,3

   1  , 2,      3
   ```

   This can trip you up when using the prepended , to create an array of one item. Say you have a cmdlet that takes an `Array` as a parameter but you want to supply only one element that itself is an `Array`. For example,

   ```
   new-object collections.arraylist ,(1,2,3)
   New-Object : Cannot convert 'System.Object[]' to the type 'System.String' required by parameter 'ComObject'. Specified method is not supported.
   At line:1 char:12
   + new-object collections.arraylist ,(1,2,3)
   +            ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
   + CategoryInfo          : InvalidArgument: (:) [New-Object], ParameterBindingException
   + FullyQualifiedErrorId : CannotConvertArgument,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.NewObjectCommand
   ```

   Since the space before the , was essentially ignored by the parser (, is a single character token so doesn't need separation), this was parsed as:

   ```
    new-object ("collections.arraylist",(1,2,3))
   ```

   so in this case it should be:

   ```
    new-object collections.arraylist (,(1,2,3))
   ```

   Note: @(1,2,3) would not work since 1,2,3 is already an `Array`.
3. The return statement in Powershell is not like in functional languages in that it is not the only way to produce output. Every expression that produces a value other than `void`<sup>†</sup> is sent into the pipeline, i.e. collected for return (values which are arrays are unrolled and the elements collected individually). *return* causes the function to return after the value is generated (it does not "return" the value). I am assuming that there are no values being generated by the the unseen parts of the function. However, putting $Files.gettype() into the function causes a value to be generated (a `System.RuntimeType`). Therefore, the function always returns 1 more object than before. I have to assume that the case of 0 matching files was not tested (the function already works for this case, right?) because now we are back to one object so the function returns a "value" again (`System.RuntimeType`). I don't know how the returned objects are being used but there is no mention of problems caused by the first element of the `ArrayList` being a `System.RuntimeType` instead of a `PSCustomObject`. Presumably, the usage did not mind getting $null for the properties which don't exist (only [String]Name and [String]Fullname are common to both `System.RuntimeType` and `System.IO.FileInfo`) and that `Attributes` caused no type conflicts (`System.RuntimeType.Attributes` and `System.IO.FileInfo.Attributes` are both `System.Enum` but the value of `[Collections.ArrayList].Attributes` is not a valid `IO.FileInfo.Attributes` value, or so PowerShell says).

† Assignment **statements** are of type `void` while assignment **expressions** (assignments within an expression) have non-void type. Thus,

```
$a = 5;       // void
($a = 5)      // int
($a = 5);     // also int
if ($a = 5){} // valid
// the assignment is evaluated as part of a conditional expression (value 5 -> $true)
```

Answer (score 1):

Collections are automatically unrolled in PowerShell as the individual elements are passed down the pipeline. If you want to guarantee that a variable remains a collection even if there is only one element, there are a few tricks you can use (the examples below use `Get-Process` but any collection variable or cmdlet that returns a collection can be used):

1. Wrap your command in an array (e.g. `$myCollection = @(Get-Process)`)
2. Prefix your potential collection with a comma `,` character (e.g. `$myCollection = , (Get-Process)`

The `@()` specified an array, and you can either provide it a list of elements or use a cmdlet that may return a collection.

The `, (Get-Process)` syntax looks odd, but this is the same syntax as specifying a hardcoded list of elements for an array. Consider the following:

```
$myArray = 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, "Bender"
```

This creates an array with the elements `1`, `2`, `3`, `4`, `5`, and `"Bender"`. In the shorthand above though, merely providing the `,` as the first character in the expression signifies that this is an array, treat it as such. Due to the nature of PowerShell unrolling collections, any subsequent arrays/collections that are returned after that initial comma will be added to the final collection.